# Jquery Ajax data pass empty response to controller in Edge and IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

My code sends a group of values to my Symfony controller using AJAX. This code works in Chrome and Firefox but in IE and Edge it receives empty data.

When I try to `console.log(data)` I get an empty array in IE and Edge. In Chrome I get the right values. Any help is appreciated.

I tried answers from other questions like using `async: false`, but it didn't work.

```js
var $_data = {
  'change': '',
  'SQLServ': "sqlServ",
  'Confirm': $Confirm,
  'secu': $('#secu').val(),
  'cp': $('#cp').val(),
};

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "{{path('manage_test_php')}}",
  data: $_data,
  success: function(data) {

  },
  beforeSend: function() {
    $('.loader').show();
  },
  complete: function() {
    $('.loader').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Is the data sent in the request the same in all browsers? Is IE/Edge receiving no data, or is there an error returned instead?

Comment: that's the problem in all the browser the request is sent without errors but in edge and IE it's empty while in chrome and firefox it does have data values

Comment: So in that case this isn't an AJAX problem, but an issue with how you collate the data to be sent. Everything in the example above seems fine, except `$Confirm`. What is that and how is it calculated?

Comment: I forget to add the function this code in `SaveBaseinfos($Confirm){}`, that's where `$Confirm` come from. and I tried removing all variables and send a static value but I get the same response.

Comment: What is the value of `$Confirm`?

Comment: In this case it's '17'.

Comment: Can you reproduce this is a jsfiddle where you get weather or a single string?

Comment: No, the code does work in jsfiddle. does this mean my symfony project has a problem ? the weird part is that chrome work without a problem.

Comment: since what is returned from php is empty (or interpreted as empty) and if the data you sent is valid, then the problem is most likely in your php code ... which you omit. so perhaps you return invalid stuff and chrome is more fault tolerant, who might know? what does your network log tell you? what does your console tell about errors?

Comment: putting `console.log(data);` in `success: function(data){}` return an empty array in console doesn't that mean that the data being sent to php is empty in the first place?

Comment: wouldn't trust it. really look in the network tab to see what's returned (raw data perhaps). check your requests on hop at a time. also look at the data being sent TO the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumble upon this question, I found a solution. it seems adding `cache:false` after success did the trick.

example:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{path('manage_test_php')}}",
    data: $_data,
    success: function(data) {

    },
    cache:false,
    beforeSend: function() {
    $('.loader').show();
    },
    complete: function() {
    $('.loader').hide();
    }
    });
```